# Can I do Principal Component analysis as a first step for linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, pca

If I have many predictor variables, instead of performing backward or forward selection, can I do PCA as a first step and then go ahead with linear regression?

Comment: What down side do you see? Why not?